# Switch inside switch alternative

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have this pseudocode:

```
switch (true) {
  case (cond_1 < 0):
    return 'c1 < 0';
  case (cond_1 === 0):
    switch (true) {
      case (cond_2 < 0):
        return 'c2 < 0'
      case (cond_2 === 0):
        return 'c2 === 0'
      default:
        return 'c2 > 0'
    }
  default:
    return 'c1 > 0';
}
```

Is there a better way to write this code, without using switch inside other switch statement?

Comment: You should be using if/else conditions here. This isn't really what `switch` is meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `if/else` conditions are more compact, and the flow is easier to read:

```
if (cond_1 < 0) return 'c1 < 0';
if (cond_1 === 0) {
  if (cond_2 < 0) return 'c2 < 0';
  if (cond_2 === 0) return 'c2 === 0';
  if (cond_2 > 0) return 'c2 > 0';
}
return 'c1 > 0';
```